# How to have Google Sheets send an email based on key words from Google Form submission

Tags: google-apps-script

I am new to this stuff, but have a question that I can't find an answer to. I am making a custom CRM system for my company. When a customer calls, the answering employee will fill out a google form. They have to pick a project manager from a list. When they submit the form, I want an email to be automatically sent to that project manager notifying him that he has a new customer that he needs to contact.

Thanks for your help. Please let me know any additional information I'd need to share to get this created in the Script for the sheet that populates with the results from the GForm.

Comment: will dropdown contain the email address, if not, where it is stored

Comment: I can include the email addresses in the google form if necessary. My hope was to make the "send email" function conditional on which name is selected on the google form. For example, if in the google form someone were to select my name "Eric" and submit the form, then an email would be sent to my email address "blahblah@lkjlkj.com". If someone picked "Brad", then an email would go to his email, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Well, lets assume that your going to organize your form so that you will get responses in this order and with these headers

TimeStamp,ManagerName,CustomerName,Phone,EmailAddress,

```
function hookMeUpToFormSubmitTrigger(e)
{
  var managerEmail={Brad:'email1@xxx.com',Eric:'email2@xxy.com'};//Could be drawn from contact sheets
  var contactTime=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(e.namedValue.TimeStamp), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "E MMM d, HHmm");
  MailApp.sendEmail({to: managerEmail[e.namedValues.ManagerName],subect: 'New Customer: ' + e.namedValues.CustomerName,htmlBody: 'Just letting you know that ' + e.namedValues.CustomerName + ' called at ' + contactTime + ' They would like a call back at your ealiest convenient time.  Their phone number is ' + e.namedValues.Phone + ' and their email address is ' + e.namedValues.EmailAddress + '.' });

}
```

Comment: So you're saying that if I were to organize my form to output information in that order, I can go in and input the email addresses I need to use and it should function correctly?

Comment: It's not necessary to put thing in that order.  I just needed to know what they order was then adjust the code to fit the order.  And as far as the managers emails go.  You can store them in a spreadsheet and read them out into an object (sometimes called an associative array that is a little easier to understand when you read the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add email id in the dropdown. Then you need to create form bound script and then add below script. Once done you need to schedule a trigger for the below function on submit of form.

```
function collectResponse(e) {
    try {
        var itemResponses = e.response.getItemResponses();
        var emailAddress = itemResponses[0].getResponse(); //change the index to match your email address dropdown
        var customerInfo = itemResponses[1].getResponse(); //change the index to match your customer info input box
        MailApp.sendEmail({
            to: emailAddress,
            subject: "New customer " + customerInfo,
            //body: add if you want to send more details
        })
    } catch (e) {
        Logger.log(e)
    }
}
```